# issue with accessing for loop variable inside Ajax functions

Tags: ajax, variables

I have a problem accessing for loop variable inside my AJAX functions. Below is my code.

```
for (var x; x<=8; x++){
    $('#sumbit_button'+x).bind('keyup paste', function(value){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.post('index.php', {val : val }, function(data){
            $('#sumbit_this_'+x).html(data);
            verify_error(value);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a helpful explanation

Comment: It realy "doesn't work" bro!

Comment: still useless. What do you see? Any JS errors?

Comment: I have edited my code above, I am trying to pass the variable 'x' to variable 'value'. Is that making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$('#sumbit_button'+x).bind('keyup paste', function(x){ ... }
```

Means that your previously defined variable `x` is overriden in local function scope by function argument `x` which is actually the `keyup` or `paste` event. If you want to keep reference to `x`, rename `function(x){...}` to something more logical, like `function(event) {...}` or do not use function argument at all if you don't need it `function(){...}`.

It would be a good idea to read more about how jQuery and Javascript event handlers work.

**Update**

Your current version of the script will not work either because you're still passing jQuery event object to the `verify_error` instead of `x`. The problem is that you do not pass `x` when declaring an event handler, you're declaring a **new variable**, which is currently called `value`. Delete the variable **value** from `$('#sumbit_button'+x).bind('keyup paste', function(value){...}`  and simply pass 'x' to the `verify_error` as in the first version of your script.

Comment: I've tried doing like what fapDaddy suggested. And still got no result.

Comment: Read update. Read more about closures here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score -1):

You've overwritten the `x` by your `function(x)`

Try renaming `x` in `function(x)` to something else like `function(y)` or whatever that make sense.

```
for (var x; x<=8; x++){
    $('#sumbit_button'+x).bind('keyup paste', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.post('index.php', {val : val }, function(data){
            $('#sumbit_this_'+x).html(data);
            verify_error(x);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your variable "value" has no value in it.

Comment: @user2310422 right, my mistake. Just remove the `value` from `function(value)` and `verify_error(value)`. Since that you only wanted to read the `x` which is from the for loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: @user2310422 also, you might have misspelled your button id: `#sumbit_button` instead of `#submit_button`.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to do since from the beginning. These two line $('#sumbit_this_'+x).html(data); verify_error(x); can't get the variable scope from the for loop statement